# Java Tree With Predecessor and Successor

Tags: java, tree

I am trying to find an implementation of a Tree which has both predecessors and successors. For example, family tree where we have
- a selected contact (root)
- his/her parents, grandparents etc.
- his/her children, grandchildren etc.
Ideally it would look as follows:

```
GF1  GM1   GF2  GM2  
    F         M  
        Root  
    S         D  
GS1   GD1  GS2
```

where 
GF - Grand Father
GM - Grand Mother
F - Father
M - Mother
S - Son
D - Daughter
GS - Grand Son
GD - Grand Daughter

I have found several tree implementations but none of them allow to draw the hierarchy like above.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: just a question: your issue is, that you cannot draw the tree? (i'm asking if you have a proper model and only lack the drawing then the question should be re-worded)... or are you looking for a proper model that can represent your data (and drawing comes later, best in seperate question)

Comment: I have a model already which retrieves data from DB but the question is how to properly draw a tree. For example, there is a nice implementation of a tree display: **abego** but they lack the facility to draw the tree with parents and children.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a Binary tree should do fine for you (assuming that all nodes have at most two children - male and female).

Also, when designing the abstract `Node` for the tree, you could add pointers to the left and right parents (i.e. mother and father), additionally to the pointers to the left and right children.

```
class Node {
    Node mother;
    Node father;
    Node son;
    Node daughter;
}
```

Note that when adding a `Node` to the tree, you should not only update the reference in the current node for which you add a new successor/predecessor, but you should add a reference of the current node the successor/predecessor as well.

This will allow you to navigate up and down from a selected (root) node.

Comment: might i suggest to have a `List<Node> childList` to enable the Node to have a different amount of children (not only **one** son and **one** daughter)? besides that that would be a very suitable solution!

Comment: Unfortunately, there might be several sons and several daugthers. In that case we need an n-ary tree. This actually works if you try to display just children or just parents.
The problem is to display **both** parents and children at the same time.

Comment: are you sure you need a **binary tree**, rather than a mere **tree** ?

Comment: @MartinFrank, you're right. :) In this case there should be two lists - `childList` and `parentList`

Answer (score 0):

you need a custom widget, a kind of which is in any case just a `Table`

if you know that a Tree is merely a simple Table implementation, you can create your custom Table and decorate is a tree

[image: table representing a tree]

all children/parents are indented according to the depth, so parent are in depth 1, parent.parent are in depth 2, the same applies for children.

whenever a row has an entry you can (should) draw the tree symbol, it's a `+` sign when the column is equal to the nodes depth or a `|` when the depth is deeper than the row.

Unluckily i know of none implementation doing so, so you'll have to do it on your own. if you have problems on implementing a table and/or a Table model feel free to ask another question!

Comment: having a `JTable`  and a `JTableModel` you can easily insert nodes at any position you want